# conversion toCelsius() Method not working properly

Tags: java, methods

I wrote a method that converts degree units to Celsius, but when I run it in the main method, it gives the wrong input.
Ideally, 212 F gives 100 C; however, the output I got was -273.15. Oh gosh. Any ideas?
*edit- I missed the break; the first time so I got that. After the insertion, I got a number of 0.0, below are my most current code.

```
public class Temperature {
    private double degree;
    private char degreeUnit;
    

    public Temperature(double degree, char degreeUnit) {
        this.degree= degree;
        this.degreeUnit= degreeUnit;
    }
    public Temperature toCelsius() {
        switch(this.degreeUnit) {
        case 'F':
            this.degree=(this.degree-32)* (5/9);
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
            break;
        case 'K':
            this.degree=this.degree-273.15;
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
            break;
        default:
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public class TemperatureDemo
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Temperature temp5 = new Temperature(212, 'F');
        System.out.println(temp5.toCelsius());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put in `break` statements after your cases.  Otherwise, they just fall thru to the next.

```
        case 'F':
            this.degree=(this.degree-32)* (5/9);
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
            break;
        case 'K':
            this.degree=this.degree-273.15;
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
            break;
        default:
            this.degreeUnit= 'C';
```

A couple other problems.

One problem is (5/9). That is integer math and results in 0. Try (5./9)

And override toString in your temperature class to print the values when you specify the object.  Something like:

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return degree + " " + degreeUnit;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate that; I missed the fudementals. After I added them, I got 0. Maybe there are other mistakes in my code?

Comment: The problem is (5/9).  That is integer math and results in 0. Try (5./9).

Comment: Didn’t think of that. Will try! You have enlightened me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"break;" command is missing in your switch statement. Please add "break;" to your switch statement .Example from W3school( https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp)

switch(expression) {
case x:
// code block
break;
case y:
// code block
break;
default:
// code block
}